# Can not load image in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to load image and video in JavaFX.The related part of my code is given below where video loading part is okay but Image loading part is not working.Can you give me the solution?

```
if (serialvalue == 1) {
    String infoquery = "select * from information where " + "categoryname like " + "'%" + selectedcategory + "%'";
    try {
        filename = getFilePathForCorrespodingSerial(infoquery, serialvalue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("You path for video : " + filename);
    System.out.println("my choiche");
    //File path = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\RGACD_Directory\\arosh.jpg");
    java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\RGACD_Directory\\arosh.jpg");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    im = new ImageView(new Image(fis));
    String newpath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\RGACD_Directory\\" + filename;
    me1 = new Media(new File(newpath).toURI().toString());
    mp1 = new MediaPlayer(me1);
    mv1.setMediaPlayer(mp1);
    mp1.setAutoPlay(true);
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that `C:\Users\User\Downloads\RGACD_Directory\arosh.jpg` exists and is a valid image?

Comment: Yes, I verify that and there is no error message for that. By the way What you mean by valid of an image?

Comment: If you double-click the file, does it display correctly?

Comment: yes, i checked it

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
final ImageView im = new ImageView(
            new Image(new File("C:/Users/User/Downloads/RGACD_Directory/arosh.jpg").toURI().toString()));
```

Comment: /*
I used this but still not working.
*/
@FXML
 public void button(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
  FileChooser fC = new FileChooser();
  fC.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads"));
  fC.getExtensionFilters()
    .addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Video : ", "*.jpg", "*.png"));

  File selectedvideo1 = fC.showOpenDialog(null);
  System.out.println(selectedvideo1);

  if (selectedvideo1 != null) {
   String path = selectedvideo1.getAbsolutePath();
   System.out.println(path);
   im2=new ImageView(new Image(new File(path).toURI().toString()));
  
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us the stack trace. 
Try this, put the image file in the package where your java file resides and write the code as:

```
ImageView icon = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/main/view/images/inbox.png")));
```

The main package is just after the src directory.

In my case, My java file is in the view package. Also note that in window we use '\\' as separators and in linux we use backslash (/).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this works for me:

```java
@FXML
ImageView im;
im.setImage(new Image("file:///C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\arosh.png");
```